# Crossfade two ore more strings in MySQL or MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm looking for a lean way of overlapping/crossfading two or more strings in MySQL or MariaDB.

There is a base string like this:

```
XXXOOOOOOOXXX
```

Then there are n strings that need to crossfade that base string. The rule in this demo case is that X should be priority. The strings can be of different length.

So this strings overlapping the base string:

```
OOOOOXOOOOOOOOOX
XXOOOXXOOOOOXXXXO
```

should result in:

```
XXXOOXXOOOXXXXXXO
```

I could do this in PHP, but maybe there is a function inside MySQL or MariaDB that makes it faster.

Comment: Please explain what "crossfade" means.  It is not a word I am familiar with.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just a speculation, it seems to be some kind of bitwise operation, where the "bits" are `X` and `O`.

Comment: I tried to explain it in the example. The strings are put on each other, while the X char always has priority and writes over the O char.

Comment: If you can transform the character strings into (chunks of) bit strings  where "O" is 0 and "X" is 1 shorter strings right padded to the length of the longer one (and back), you could use binary or: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a7fbdba3f9b60e57b4ecbf29b5863af3

Comment: Sounds interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a string of CTE's that show a way of doing what @stickybit suggested: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=bc9ee04072f2faaa7ab0a4e9c3c5a196

Comment: nice. will take some time to check that out. works only in MariaDB.

Comment: Let's see more examples.  Can there be 3 different letters?  What if the second string starts with `O`?  What if the first string is longer than the second?  What is meant by "priority"?  Is "fade" a term in dealing with light or color?

Comment: 3 different letters are in my case not needed.

Comment: @Mike it will also work in MySQL 8. But you could also use that code to generate a function to do the job for you; that could work in MySQL 5.x too.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a function in MySQL which does do that, but one can be created:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `crossfade`(
    a VARCHAR(100), 
    b VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET utf8mb4
BEGIN
   DECLARE i INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
   DECLARE r VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
   -- Make input equally long
   IF LENGTH(a) < LENGTH(b) THEN
      SET A = RPAD(A,LENGTH(b),' ');
   ELSE
      SET B = RPAD(B,LENGTH(a),' ');
   END IF;
   WHILE i<=LENGTH(a) DO
       IF substring(a,i,1)='X' THEN
         SET r = concat(r,substring(a,i,1));
       ELSE
         SET r = concat(r,substring(b,i,1));
       END IF;
       SET i = i + 1;
   END WHILE;
RETURN r;
END
```

Example:

```
SELECT crossfade('OOOOOXOOOOOOOOOX','XXOOOXXOOOOOXXXXO');
```

output:

```
+ ------------------------------------------------------ +
| crossfade('OOOOOXOOOOOOOOOX','XXOOOXXOOOOOXXXXO')      |
+ ------------------------------------------------------ +
| XXOOOXXOOOOOXXXXO                                      |
+ ------------------------------------------------------ +
```